# Calculate statistically needed tries to rech consensus.

Tags: probability, problem-solving

I'm working on an experimental consensus algorithm for a blockchain oracle service (trying to learn about it at least) and I have a simple question whether a certain property is even calculatable or not. I'm not thaaat math savy actually but sometimes I think I am. :D

So... we have lots of smarties, red and green ones. :) Around 49% of them are red and 51% are green. I wanna pick 3 with the same color in a row. If I pick one of a different color I eat them all and try again. So there's a certain probability of achieving that but what I wanna know is... is there a way to mathematically approximate the number of smarties I will need to eat until I succeed? For each color separately?

I have a simulation of that and it shows me an average value of how many "smarties" it ate.

```
Corrupted oracles:                   33% (3300/10000)
Confirmations needed per request:    10
---
Data Requests:                       1000
Involved oracles per request (avg):  188.49 (x18.85 of minimum)
Correct consensus:                   999 (99.90%)
False consensus:                     1 (0.10%)
No consensus:                        0 (0.00%)
```

The corrupted oracles are our red smarties here. The simulation assumes 33% out of 10k overall.
It tries to pick 10 "same colored smarties" in a row and tries that 1000 times. In this example it needed to eat on average 188.49 smarties until it had eaten 10 same colored ones in a row.

**Question: Can this number somehow be calculated based on for example 33% red and 10 same ones in a row?**

**Additional question: Can I calculate the number of corrupted oracles/red smarties with that number?**

---

While I hope for enlightening answers I'll edit this and explain a bit more...

Ok so... As I said, I am playing a round with blockchain oracles. Just wanna learn about it. But doesn't matter anyway. Basically I want to amplify a given distribution, so that chances of hitting the sliiightly bigger chunk become much higher than for example 49/51. I'm doing that by simply chaining the probabilities and I realized that this changes the relation. And actually I tested my script with a 49% corruption value and et voilà:

```
Corrupted oracles:                   49% (4900/10000)
Confirmations needed per request:    10
---
Data Requests:                       1000
Involved oracles per request (avg):  1496.85 (x149.69 of minimum)
Correct consensus:                   609 (60.90%)
False consensus:                     390 (39.00%)
No consensus:                        1 (0.10%)
```

Still 60% correct consensus. BUT also 40% false consensus. We accidentally ate 10 red smarties in a row. So given the fact that when all smarties are eaten the result is simply "No consensus" (safe failure), there must be a way to (statistically) force the smaller side into "No consensus" by setting the right amount of maximum involved oracles (smarties).

Does that make sense or am I going in circles here?

---

Simulation script can be found here: https://github.com/mktcode/simplor-node

---

**Update**

```
Corrupted oracles:                   33% (3300/10000)
Confirmations needed per request:    10
---
Data Requests:                       1000
Involved oracles per request (good): 189.51 (x18.95 of minimum)
Involved oracles per request (bad):  898.00 (x89.80 of minimum)
Correct consensus:                   999 (99.90%)
False consensus:                     1 (0.10%)
No consensus:                        0 (0.00%)
```

I split up "Involved oracles per request" now into good and bad ones. So here you can clearly see, that the 1 false consensus needed 898 oracles while all the correct ones only needed 189.51 on average. That is the very significant difference that results from chaining the probabilities, even if the network is 49% corrupt and I'm wondering if that might be an interesting thing.

Comment: If I understood this right, you contact 3 oracles. They could either be red or green. 49% of oracles are red on average. 51% of oracles are green on average. You are looking for the probability of NOT(red x red x red OR green x green x green)

Comment: Are there enough smarties that we can assume that eating them doesn't materially alter the distribution?  If so, then the number of times you have to choose is geometrically distributed, and the calculation is easy.  You might try assuming sampling with replacement first, and see if it agrees well enough with your simulations.

Comment: @vvgiri The OP is looking for an expectation, not a probability.

Comment: Followup to @saulspatz's comment (directed to the OP): During a trial do the oracles go back into the selection pool or they go back after you complete 3 (or 10) as the case may be? What I mean is can two consecutive oracle connects be made to the same oracle within a  10-pick?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know myself what I am looking for I'm really just playing with numbers a bit and hope something useful comes out but so far it looks at least interesting enough. Anyway... gimme a moment. I need to think. :D But already thanks for the comments.

Comment: @vvgiri I'm not contacting 3 oracles. I'm contacting the whole network but it is ensured that answers can be handles sequentially because they write results in a blockchain themselves.

Comment: @saulspatz There should be enough smarties/oracles. Retying x times when no consensus is found is also an option. For now the oracles listen for an event and write data, more or less at the same time but the blockchain buts them in order. The writes are our smartie picks.

Comment: @saulspatz and do I understand to suggest to feed the simulated results into the formular and try to approximate "manually" or do I misunderstand? I'd also be glad about some quality resources on the topic in general. Geometrically distributed? No intuitive idea what that really means for example. :D

Comment: @vvgiri No, an oracle can only respond once. As I mention in another comment, retry rounds would be possible though. And when the required number of consecutive results is reached, they are returned to the requesting party and another request will be handled where all oracles can respond again.

Comment: btw I have the script online: https://github.com/mktcode/simplor-node If you have used npm before should be no problem. clone, install, run.

Comment: @saulspatz Ok, I know now what sampling with or without replacement means. So no, it is without replacement, as an oracle will only be asked once per request. If it causes a deviation of previously stored responses it removes them all and itself. So the smarties are actually eaten. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started out making it a comment, but it got too long.

Suppose that the probability that all the smarties is $p$.  If you put the smarties back when they're not all the same color, the then expected number of trials until you get a sample that's all the same color is $\frac1p$.  (This is what I meant by sampling with replacement and a geometric distribution.)

If you don't put them back, then calculating the exact expectation is laborious, and I would recommend simulation instead.  However, it may be that the simple calculation described in the first paragraph is good enough for your needs.  Suppose, in the initial population, half are green smarties and half are are red.  If you randomly choose $10$ smarties, the probability that they are all the same color is $\frac1{512}$, and it will take, on average, $512$ trials to get a monochrome sample.  If you were sampling without replacement, you would have removed $5120$ smarties from the jar.

If you started out with $20,000$ smarties, removing $5,000$ of them might have a material effect on the distribution of colors in the population.  If you started out with a million smarties, not so much.  This is what I was getting at in my comment.  If your population is large, you may be able to get an answer that is close enough for your purposes by ignoring the effect of removing the smarties, and assuming instead that they are replaced.

I'm not a javascript programmer, so I'm not sure I understand your code, but in fact I do not see where your simulation is removing the sampled items.

Comment: Ok, first of all thanks a lot. This made some things feel much clearer in my head. I had this "ah sure of course" moment. :D
For the code: https://git.io/JUr0j Here a deviation check is made and the list of picked "smarties" (responses) is emptied.
and... isn't it 1/1024?

Comment: This issue with affecting the remaining distribution is something I need to think about a bit. When I have `1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1` and if I take away the first half then the distribution in the remaining set changed. That's what you mean.. kind of? The thing is... I will need some form of preselection anyway because in the end, we are talking about computers sending data over a network and I need to make sure that connection speed has no effect on the distribution. Would otherwise mean: If you want to manipulate... have a fast connection and your good to go.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer The probability that all are red is $1/1024$; the probability that all are green is $1/1024$  The probability that all are the same color is $1/512.$  Yes, if you remove some of the smarties, you change the distribution of the remaining smarties a little bit.  I don't understand the last sentence of your last comment.  Perhaps you ought to explain the problem you are actually working on, rather than making an analogy with candies.

Comment: I updated the post and explained it a bit more. It's an oracle system. A network of independent and unknown nodes that processes data requests. It needs to facilitate some form of consensus but asking all nodes is not really feasable, so a random subset needs to be found that finds a consensus. I'm all in all really new in this space so I just try to understand and play around with my own ideas. And currently my experimental learning project is a "trustless" oracle system.

Comment: ...where really anybody can spawn a node and help providing somewhat trusted data to immutable storage, from all kinds of APIs. You'll also get at least some form of compensation that pays the 0.1ct it costs to run it or depending on the economic model I still have to figure out maybe even make some passive income.

Comment: But this system has to be at least byzantine fault tolerant, tolerating up to at least 1/3 corruption. I'm not very sure thought whether that refers to organized corruption, where all corrupted nodes try to scam the system the same way or 1/3 of arbitrarily failing nodes. My system assumes organized attacks.

Comment: btw... marked you're answer correct. It's more a discussion than a concrete answer anyway and you helped a lot already.